# Implement __eq__ for Python objects that contain deeply nested numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I'm having problems with numpy arrays not being comparable with `==` (using the semantics of `np.array_equal`) in the context of object attributes.

Consider the following example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
...
>>> x = A(a=[1, np.array([1, 2])])
>>> y = A(a=[1, np.array([1, 2])])
>>> x == y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-33-9cfbd892cdaa>", line 1, in <module>
    x == y
  File "<ipython-input-30-790950997d4f>", line 5, in __eq__
    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

(ignore that `__eq__` isn't perfect, it should at least check the type of `other`, but this is for the sake of brevity)

How would I implement an `__eq__` function that handles numpy arrays being nested deep inside my object attributes (assuming everything else, such as the list in this example, compares fine with `==`)? The numpy arrays might occur at an arbitrarily deep nesting level inside lists, tuples, or dicts.

I've tried coming up with a "manual" implementation of a recursive `eq` function that applies `==` to all attributes, and uses `np.array_equal` whenever it comes across a numpy array, but this is trickier than expected.

Does anybody have a suitable function, or an easy workaround?

Comment: `np.all_close` seems to be a robust way of comparing numpy arrays.

Comment: I'm aware of `np.all_close`, but `==` should always be exact equality, which is what I'm interested in here. Besides, this does not address the problem of numpy arrays not implementing `==`, and thus not being able to work correctly in nested comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option to change the objects `x` and `y`, you could overwrite the `__eq__` method of `np.ndarray` according to your preference.

```
class eqarr(np.ndarray):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self, other)

class A:
     def __init__(self, a):
         self.a = a
     def __eq__(self, other):
         return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

x = A(a=[1, eqarr([1, 2])])
y = A(a=[1, eqarr([1, 2])])
x == y
```

This resutls in `True`.

If this is not possible, the only solution I can think of at the moment is to actually implement a recursive equality check function. My attempt is the following:

```
def eq(a, b):
    if not (hasattr(a, '__iter__') or type(a) == str):
        return a == b

    try:
        if not len(a) == len(b):
            return False

        if type(a) == np.ndarray:
            return np.array_equal(a, b)
        if isinstance(a, dict):
            return all(eq(v, b[k]) for k, v in a.items())
        else:
            return all(eq(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b))
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        return False


class A:
     def __init__(self, a):
         self.a = a
     def __eq__(self, other):
         return eq(self.__dict__, other.__dict__)
```

With your examples and all those that I came up with it worked. The solution should be applicable whenever the nested ojects have an `__iter__` and a `__len__` attribute.

I hope that I accounted for all possible errors, but you may need to adjust the code a little bit to make it absolutely fail-safe.

If you find a counterexample, please provide it as a comment. I am sure the code can be adjusted accordingly.

The performance of `eq` may not be great, but I do not know whether this is a major concern to you.

If numpy arrays are rather rare in your hierarchy (and often close to the top), you could always try a normal comparison first. This could look like the following:

```
def eq(a, b):
    try:
        return np.all(a == b)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        if not len(a) == len(b):
            return False

        if type(a) == np.ndarray:
            return np.array_equal(a, b)
        if isinstance(a, dict):
            return all(eq(v, b[k]) for k, v in a.items())
        else:
            return all(eq(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b))
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        return False
```

Comment: Changing the objects is not an option, unfortunately

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of the deeply nested lists (with and without your desired new object)?

Comment: I might have `a=(1, [1, {'key': np.array([1, 2])}, [1, [np.array([1,2])]]], 2)` or `a=[1, [MyMutableSequence([1, np.array([1,2])]),1]]`

Comment: Sure, implementing a recursive `eq` manually is possible (and what I started out with), but I fear that it will be nearly impossible to get something very general that won't have bugs for weird edge cases.

Comment: What do you know about the objects in the nested structure? How general does it have to be? Sure, it is easy to construct classes that will make my solution fail. But do you need it to work that generally? (I understand that my solution is not very elegant and that you may have come up with something similar or even better before - it would have been nice to get more specific information on what the issues were that you ran into.)

Comment: The values for `a` are user-supplied objects, so, strictly speaking, I cannot make any assumptions about them. It won't be hard to make it work for the 99.9% most common data, but I hate to have loose ends that will blow up in very subtle ways when someone passes something unusual.